# Partial sums of exponential series as a reduced fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The partial sum of the exponential series can be written as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!} = \frac{nt+1}{n!}
$$
When is this fraction a reduced fraction?

More precisely, when does the reduced form of this fraction have denominator $n!$ ?

Here is some data:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue}1 & \color{blue}2 & 3 & \color{blue}4 & 5 & \color{blue}6 & 7 & \color{blue}8 & 9 & \color{blue}{10}
\\ \hline \\
S_n & \frac{1}{1} & \frac{1}{1} & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{8}{3} & \frac{65}{24} & \frac{163}{60} & \frac{157}{720} & \frac{685}{252} & \frac{109601}{40320} &  \frac{98641}{36288} & \frac{9864101}{3628800}
\\ \\
n! & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 24 & 120 & 720 & 5040 & 40320 & 362880 & 3628800
\end{array}
$$

The denominators are given by [oeis.org/A061355](http://oeis.org/A061355).
See also [oeis.org/A093101](http://oeis.org/A093101).

Comment: Motivated by http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070526/can-i-demonstrate-that-this-final-sum-is-natural-number.

Comment: For $n$ odd it is reduced if and only if $n=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, proof?

Comment: What is $t$? Does $t$ depend on $n$?

Comment: @Raclette, it does.